# Using Split in Java and substring the result

Tags: java, substring, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [string split in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/string-split-in-java)

I have this `Key - Value` , and I want to separate them from each other and get return like below:

```
String a = "Key"
String b = "Value"
```

so whats the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: Have you tried String.split(...) ?

Comment: I am a php developer so its kinda different , but now I know my mistake , it was using single quotation in the split method

Comment: @Salah Yahya: Next time, try to also mention what you already tried inside the question, that way it has more value for future visitors. I even encourage you rewriting this question so it indicates a bit more effort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String[] tok = "Key - Value".split(" - ", 2);
// TODO: check that tok.length==2 (if it isn't, the input string was malformed)
String a = tok[0];
String b = tok[1];
```

The `" - "` is a regular expression; it can be tweaked if you need to be more flexible about what constitutes a valid separator (e.g. to make the spaces optional, or to allow multiple consecutive spaces).

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\s*-\\s*");
String a = parts[0];
String b = parts[1];
```

Comment: +1 I prefer the more flexible regex over `" - "`

Answer (score 3):

```
int idx = str.indexOf(" - ");
String a = str.substring(0, idx);
String b = str.substring(idx+3, str.length());
```

`split()` is a bit more computation intensive than `indexOf()`, but if you don't need to split billions of times per seconds, you don't care.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "Key - Value";
String[] arr = s.split("-");
String a = arr[0].trim();
String b = arr[1].trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

I like using [StringUtils.substringBefore](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBefore%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [StringUtils.substringAfter](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringAfter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from the belowed Jakarta Commons Lang library.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
String[] parts = "Key - Value".split(" - ");
String a = parts[0];
String b = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

As a little bit longer alternative:

```
    String text = "Key - Value";
    Pattern pairRegex = Pattern.compile("(.*) - (.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pairRegex.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String a = matcher.group(1);
        String b = matcher.group(2);
    }
```